Blend two bezier curve using partitionof unity property while ensuring interpolation
I have two Bezier curve, say c1 and c2, these curves are interpolating the data points, while the given data points have some common points. i want to blend/merge them to a single curve while ensuring continuity and interpolation. Hower i got something like

the resulting curve is not interpolating the given data points of both c1 and c2 curves. I used weight functions as w1=1-u and w2=u.
is there any way i can get the blending curve while ensuring the interpolation of given data also?

Without code, it's impossible to see what you actually did. From the looks of it, you're interpolating the entire curves, not just the points in the overlapping region. Also note that you can't losslessly merge two Bezier curves into one curve, you need to construct a new curve the same start and end points you want, and then derive the control points based on the fact that the tangent at the start and end point is fixed (so the line(s) that the controls lie on are fixed), and then finding control points that minimize the error wrt the original curves.
